# React Native release version built successfully but does not work like debug

Tags: react-native, release

I build the release version to publish, but it don't comunicate with my api, however, the debug version works fine.

Is there a way to debug an release version to find what is happening? I tried to open dev tools but it doest work.

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe its because you are not using a secure api.
try adding this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- < add this line > -->

<application
...
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" <!-- < add this line > -->
/>
...
</application>
```

Comment: That's it!! Thankk you verymuch!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can debug your release apk in android studio and can se the logcat there you can find out what error you are into.